# Using SQL date functions in Carto

Tags: carto, sql

I'm having difficult using basic date functions in cartodb.

This could be my formatting or syntax, but I'm stuck.

I simply want to show customers on my map that have not been visited in the last 90 days.  I have a table of geocoded customer points and a column 'last_visit'.

The following sql statements fail:

```
SELECT  datediff('d', last_visit, currdate()) FROM table_2016_10_26_geocoded_pids_y
```

'fucntion currdate() does not exist'

```
SELECT  datediff('d', last_visit, curdate()) FROM table_2016_10_26_geocoded_pids_y
```

'fucntion curdate() does not exist'

```
SELECT  datediff('d', last_visit, today()) FROM table_2016_10_26_geocoded_pids_y
```

'function today() does not exist'

```
SELECT  datediff(d, last_visit, curdate()) FROM table_2016_10_26_geocoded_pids_y
```

'unknown column d'

```
SELECT  datediff('dd', last_visit, now()) FROM table_2016_10_26_geocoded_pids_y
```

function datediff(unknown, timestamp with time zone, timestamp with time zone) does not exist

'column d does not exist'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nevermind, this is Postgres SQL.  I found the answer:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24929735/postgresql-how-to-calculate-date-difference-in-postgresql

```
SELECT * FROM table_2016_10_26_geocoded_pids_y where EXTRACT(DAY FROM now()-last_visit)>90
```